# Getting Null UserAttributes in Cognito CustomMessage_ForgotPassword event in Go

Tags: go, amazon-cognito

I am sending password reset link to my users using cognito CustomMessage_ForgotPassword event. Here is my handler code.

```
func handler(ctx context.Context, event *events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage) (*events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage,error)
{
resetURL := fmt.Sprintf("%s/login/recover", os.Getenv("DOMAIN_URL"))
var customMessageForgotPassword = fmt.Sprintf(
    `<style>
    p {
    display: block;
    }
    </style>

    <div tabindex="-1"><p>Hello,</p>
    <p> Click on link below to reset your password.</p>
    <p><a href="%s?code=%s&email=%s"> Reset Password </a></p>
    <p>Thanks</p>
    </div>`,
    resetURL,
    event.Request.CodeParameter, event.Request.UserAttributes["Email"])

if event.TriggerSource == "CustomMessage_ForgotPassword" {
    event.Response.EmailMessage = customMessageForgotPassword
    event.Response.EmailSubject = "Reset Your Password"
}

return event, nil


}
```

Here is the definition of CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessageRequest in cognito.go file.

```
type CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage struct {
CognitoEventUserPoolsHeader
Request  CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessageRequest  `json:"request"`
Response CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessageResponse `json:"response"`
}

type CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessageRequest struct {
UserAttributes    map[string]interface{} `json:"userAttributes"`
CodeParameter     string                 `json:"codeParameter"`
UsernameParameter string                 `json:"usernameParameter"`
ClientMetadata    map[string]string      `json:"clientMetadata"`
}
```

In email I am getting Reset password url parameters like Domain_URL/login/recover?**code=13578&email=%!s()**

Tried with parameters like **UsernameParameter** and some other solutions. But always getting nil here.
Any solution to this problem?